# Beautiful soup not able to scrape all the html elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying beautiful soup to extract elements from https://www.flipkart.com/.
when I tried to print all h2 elements using the code:

````
```
for h2_tag in soup1.find_all("h2"):
    print(h2_tag)
```

<h2 class="puxlXr">Father's Day Special Gifts</h2>
<h2 class="puxlXr">Best of Appliances </h2>
<h2 class="puxlXr">Top Deals on Electronics</h2>
<h2>Flipkart Plus</h2>
<h2>No Cost EMI</h2>
<h2>EMI on Debit Cards</h2>
<h2>Mobile Exchange Offers</h2>
<h2>What Can You Buy From Flipkart?</h2>
<h2>Mobile Phones</h2>
<h2>Electronic Devices and Accessories</h2>
<h2>Large Appliances</h2>
<h2>Small Home Appliances</h2>
<h2>Lifestyle</h2>
<h2>Home and Furniture</h2>
<h2>Baby and Kids</h2>
<h2>Books, Sports and Games</h2>
<h2>Grocery/Supermart</h2>
````

Some of the elements which I can see on web are missing here. What to do in order to get all elements.

Comment: Which links are you missing?

Comment: Did you check if they're loaded through javascript queries? Cause if that's the case you might need to manually send those queries and scrape the response content, or even use selenium.